# Convert SQL query to mongo query

Tags: python, mysql, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I want to convert the following SQL to mongo query:

```
SELECT brand_name,
    count(`inventory`) AS totalstock,
    count(if(`inventory`=0, `inventory`, NULL)) as outofstock,
    count(if(`inventory`!=0, `inventory`, NULL)) as availablestock,
    DATE_ADD(stock_updated_at, INTERVAL 318 minute) as stock_updated_at 
FROM x group by Brand order by stock_updated_at desc;
```

I want to find `stock_updated_at` in project without using it on group.

This is my mongoquery

```
db.x.aggregate([     
    { 
        "$group": {       
            "_id": { "Brand": "$Brand"},        
            "TotalStock": { "$sum": 1 },       
            "OutOfStock": { "$sum": ....
       ....
   ....
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try using the existing converters.
http://www.querymongo.com/

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you can try https://github.com/alonho/pql

> PQL stands for Python-Query-Language. PQL translates python expressions to MongoDB queries.

```
>>> import pql
>>> pql.find("a > 1 and b == 'foo' or not c.d == False")
{'$or': [{'$and': [{'a': {'$gt': 1}}, {'b': 'foo'}]}, {'$not': {'c.d': False}}]}
```

Comment: In more than 4 years this module hasnt been updated and doest work with python 3.9 +